# Probability of copy/pasting from datagridview to excel breaking in future excel/.net versions?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

If I built an application that expects the user to use the copy-paste functionality from
a datagridview to excel (as a simple export), do I run a big risk that this will no longer work/give strange behavior in future builds of .net/versions of excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per this [MSDN article on copying data from a `DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dec5efh1.aspx), the control will set onto the clipboard both tab-delimited string data and an HTML table representing the data that was copied. These being relatively standard formats, as well as a relatively standard practice for exchanging data, you should be safe.

Of course, nobody can say with certainty what Microsoft will do in future versions of their products, so there's always a *chance* that something will break later on. However, Microsoft's pretty good at making things sufficiently backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 2):

There is always a risk relying on clipboard for an export implementation:

I wouldn't say it is big but you are effectively asking for trouble when exporting this way - depending on what's installed on the system (for example some background clipboard watching app) or different versions of Excel or usage of your application in a Terminal Server situation etc. - the list of things that can go wrong is "endless" IMHO.

Using some mechanism to write a real file (XLS or XLSX) is really the way to go.

There are several free and commercial libraries (which don't require Excel to be present) out there to write Excel files (some can even export the content of a `DataGridView` with less than 10 lines of code!):

- [OpenXML from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx) (free)
- [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free)
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free)
- [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) (commercial)
- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)
- [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) (commercial)
- [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) (commercial)

You can even export in "Excel-HTML format" ([sample source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kaushikborah28/79Nick08302007171404PM/79Nick.aspx) and [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a way you always run that risk when you assume certain functionality of third party program to stay around. However, Microsoft has a long history of keeping their software backward compatible for a long while, so it may not be in the next year or so that this feature will suddenly be removed.

If you must remain compatible, use another method for exchanging data.